# How to know whether actual internet is available or not in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, reachability

I want to get notified when my WiFi Router color changes from **Green** to **Red**

I am making an app which will tell you whether you are online or offline from menu bar in Swift which is open source & can be found at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/net-alert

I want to know if its possible to get notified when WiFi color changes in Swift.

I can't constantly ping my server to know that the color changed as this would be wasting internet resources.

So is it possible to know this in Swift?

Comment: Do you wan to do this for any wifi? Or just for some specific SSID? The NetworkExtension framework might be of help.

Comment: Any WiFi. I need to make a simple menu bar which changes color to `green` if internet can be reached & `red` if internet can't be reached. So if WiFi turns `red` then I need to know it somehow so I can change menu bar to `red` & same with `green` :)

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? (Noted in your question below.) Do you mean your reachability callbacks don't get called? They do get called but with the wrong values? How are you testing this? It's not very clear what the specific problem you're asking is.

Comment: @StephenDarlington My Reachability callbacks do get called. Basically, my app is   a menu bar app which will have a red color icon when internet is offline & green icon when online. What I mean by doesn't work is `I have my app open & has green color menu bar icon since internet is online but as soon as WiFi router color turns red, I need a way to get notified of the change since I need to update my menu bar to red now`. So this doesn't work as reachability notifies on WiFi connection & not color change. The way I'm testing is manually bcz my internet sucks & it goes & comes :)

Comment: How limited is your bandwidth that a ping is "wasting internet resources"? :O

Comment: @IanMacDonald its not limited but constantly pinging is just a waste. Not everyone lives where internet is super fast. People have limited MBs of internet if you didn't know :( FYI I have unlimited internet, but some people don't

Comment: Many, many, many applications use a heartbeat or health check (i.e. constant polling) of some kind for this purpose. I wouldn't worry about premature optimization until you have proven that it has a significant impact on network performance.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 i cant find the difference between internet is online/offline and the green/red colour on the router, if the connection is offline or any network error occurs the router colour turns red right?

Comment: @darismathew I am completely unaware of this but I probably think you are right :)

Comment: @IanMacDonald yeah you are right too. its a simple app & like always I am prematurely optimising. sorry about that. you are right. I shouldn't worry about it but also a good question for a curious mind :)

Comment: You may want to look into [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol). Many/most routers will provide various status information when queried via SNMP, including the state of their different network connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I'm going to answer this from iOS perspective. But your GitHub demo is for macOS. I think the basics are the same.

I'll go to solve this in protocol oriented approach.

---

### Update:

After quite a lot of searching I've come across the magnificent implementation of [Connectivity](https://github.com/rwbutler/Connectivity) wrapper. There is even a descriptive blogpost [Solving the Captive Portal Problem on iOS](https://medium.com/@rwbutler/solving-the-captive-portal-problem-on-ios-9a53ba2b381e) if you want to know more about it. ***This implementation is capable of dealing with actual internet available / not-available states.***

**Note:** Don't like to read further? [Here](https://github.com/M-I-N/ConnectivityDemo) is the working version that I'm going to illustrate briefly. Navigation bar will reflect with **Green** & **Red** color for different connection status.

### Define a protocol:

This protocol will help any interested object to be notified when any change in connectivity occurs.

```
protocol ConnectivityNotifiable {
    var connectivity: Connectivity { get }
    func startNotifyingConnectivityChangeStatus()
    func stopNotifyingConnectivityChangeStatus()
    func connectivityChanged(toStatus: ConnectivityStatus)
}

// Provide some default implementation through protocol extension
extension ConnectivityNotifiable {
    func startNotifyingConnectivityChangeStatus() {
        connectivity.isPollingEnabled = true
        connectivity.startNotifier()
        connectivity.whenConnected = { connectivity in
            self.connectivityChanged(toStatus: connectivity.status)
        }
        connectivity.whenDisconnected = { connectivity in
            self.connectivityChanged(toStatus: connectivity.status)
        }
    }
    func stopNotifyingConnectivityChangeStatus() {
        connectivity.stopNotifier()
    }
}
```

### Conform to the protocol:

Conforming to the `ConnectivityNotifiable` protocol will add the functionality to any interested object to be notified when Connectivity status changes. Something like monitoring.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ConnectivityNotifiable {

    // ConnectivityNotifiable protocol requirement
    let connectivity = Connectivity()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Invoke the default implementation of the ConnectivityNotifiable protocol
        // requirement to be able to be notified
        startNotifyingConnectivityChangeStatus()

        // Reminder:
        // Don't forget to invoke stopNotifyingConnectivityChangeStatus() when
        // you are done or when the lifecycle of your controller ends
    }

    // ConnectivityNotifiable protocol requirement
    func connectivityChanged(toStatus: ConnectivityStatus) {
        // Everytime any change happens in the network connectivity 
        // this method will be invoked with appropriate connection status
        switch toStatus {

        case .connected, 
             .connectedViaWiFi, 
             .connectedViaCellular:
            // Connected/Internet available. Update any UI component

        case .notConnected, 
             .connectedViaWiFiWithoutInternet, 
             .connectedViaCellularWithoutInternet:
            // Disconnected/Internet not available. Update any UI component
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

### Old Answer

**Note:** If you are using the latest [release](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/tree/v4.3.0) of the [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift), you won't need the `NotificationCenter` based solution to get reachability change notification. It works completely fine with closure based approach.

---

Don't like to know how to achieve this? [Here](https://github.com/M-I-N/ReachabilityDemo) is a working version made for iOS platform. Clone the repo and check yourself. Navigation bar will reflect with **Green**, **Orange** & **Red** color for different connection status.

**Define a protocol:**

This protocol will help any interested object to be notified when any change in reachability occurs.

```
protocol Reachable {
    var reachability: Reachability { get }
    func startMonitoringReachabilityChangeStatus()
    func reachabilityChanged(to: Reachability.Connection)
}

extension Reachable {
    func startMonitoringReachabilityChangeStatus() {
        do {
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
            self.reachabilityChanged(to: reachability.connection)
        }
        reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
            self.reachabilityChanged(to: reachability.connection)
        }
    }
}
```

**Conform to the protocol:**

Conforming to the `Reachable` protocol will add the functionality to any interested object to be notified when reachability status changes. Something like monitoring.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, Reachable {

    // Reachable protocol requirement
    let reachability: Reachability = Reachability()!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // initial reachability checkup
        reachabilityChanged(to: reachability.connection)

        // Invoke the default implementation of the Reachable protocol requirement 
        // to be able to be notified
        startMonitoringReachabilityChangeStatus()
    }

    // Reachable protocol requirement
    func reachabilityChanged(to: Reachability.Connection) {
        // Everytime any change happens in the network connectivity 
        // this method will be invoked with appropriate connection status
        switch to {
        case .wifi:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update any UI component
            }
        case .cellular:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update any UI component
            }
        case .none:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update any UI component
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work so I kept the same old version because both of them worked similar :) Although thanks for the solution

Comment: @deadcoder0904 hey, I've updated the answer with a new implementation. This should fulfill your requirement I hope :)

Comment: I just accepted your answer because it worked for [someone](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/issues/315#issuecomment-457640310). Thank you. I'm yet to try though :)

Comment: ConnectivityNotifiable protocol new answer worked for me.

Comment: But it is continously checking for network, will it brain the battery life ?

Comment: @MaheshPeri if you do WANT to get notified about the real internet connection status, you don't have any other option left without polling. But you can always have an one off check if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the code and the way you did doesn't notify you when the internet connection is interrupted, it just checks at the runtime whether there is connection or not.
To achieve what you want we need to add **Notifications**.

First, declare the reachability var

```
 private var reachability:Reachability!;
```

THen add the following code in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the `appdelegate`

```
 self.reachability = Reachability.init()
         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkForReachability(notification:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
        do{
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        }catch{
            print("could not start reachability notifier")
        }
```

What we do is initialise the reachability variable and create a notification observer to detect when the connection state changes with help of Notifier.

And finally the selector method is

```
@objc func checkForReachability(notification:NSNotification)
    {
        let reachability = notification.object as! Reachability
        switch reachability.connection {
        case .wifi:
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        case .cellular:
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        case .none:
            print("Network not reachable")
        }
    }
```

That's it, from now on when the internet connection is interrupted we get notified and in the above method you can change the colour of the menu bar icon.

Comment: Hey Daris, it not only works on the runtime but also when its interrupted as well. If I switch off my WiFi from the top menu bar dropdown, then it turns red & when I switch ON again, it turns green. I don't clearly understand for which use case your solution applies. Care to elaborate about it a bit?

Comment: Like you just explained the use of this code, when the wifi is OFF it should turn red and when back ON the bar should be green. So you can change the color in the respective cases.

Comment: Ahh the original one (my solution) works same as yours also stated by @nayem in above answer :)